# SQL Server 2017 - IP address is null

Tags: sql-server, jtds

I am trying to connect via Android Studio to a SQL Server database using jtds. The type of instance I'm using is a standalone.

In order to establish a connection, I am using the following statement:

```
Connection DbConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://**ip_adress:port**/**my_db**", un, pass);
```

I have tried retrieving the value of the IP address by launching the following query:

```
SELECT  
    CONNECTIONPROPERTY('net_transport') AS net_transport,
    CONNECTIONPROPERTY('protocol_type') AS protocol_type,
    CONNECTIONPROPERTY('auth_scheme') AS auth_scheme,
    CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_net_address') AS local_net_address,
    CONNECTIONPROPERTY('local_tcp_port') AS local_tcp_port,
    CONNECTIONPROPERTY('client_net_address') AS client_net_address
```

However it returns null for the fields local_net_address and local_tcp_port.

My questions are:

- Is it normal to have a null value for the ip address fields?
- Is there a way to fix this? (Aside from using the server name for my connection)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/connectionproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017` Clearly says in the Remarks... "local_net_address and local_tcp_port return NULL in SQL Database." Have you tried from the command prompt: `Ping SqlServerName`

Comment: Thank you. Yes I managed to establish a connection by retrieving the IP address through ping. It was as simple as that!